Please make the cards colored
I saw the "Ask Question", "Review your question", "Save edit", "Start writing", and "Got it" cards are black in the main site just like its meta. But black cards are for metas only. I haven't seen these cards black on any other main sites to date. The OP card also has a gray color just like the meta.
